# Android audio recording encoding/output combination for Bluemix

Tags: android, audio, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I was recording audio on Android, but it was not being recognized on the IBM Bluemix Speech to Text side. IBM supports the following - https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/speech-to-text/input.html :

- audio/flac
- audio/l16
- audio/wav
- audio/ogg;codecs=vorbis
- audio/webm;codecs=vorbis
- audio/mulaw
- audio/basic

I tried hard to get ogg/webm vorbis recording on Android, but it's not working. I was wondering if you could help me understand which of these types I could use that would work with the Bluemix API.

For encoding options I have:

```
MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC
MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC_ELD
MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB
MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB
MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC
MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.VORBIS
MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT
```

For output format options I have:

```
MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4
MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AAC_ADTS
MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB
MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_WB
MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP
MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.WEBM
MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT
```

I have not been able to find the right combination that works with Bluemix API. Please recommend some combinations to try. Is there one?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to FLAC or PCM/WAVE from this list: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html

Comment: Thanks @tmarkiewicz for your comment - i am stuck on this for very long - I just looked and I don't think MediaRecorder support FLAC or PCM/WAV because I don't see it available here - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.html#VORBIS OR here - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.html#WEBM